# Mustache(-like) template engine for Express?

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

Is there a template engine for Express (node.js) which is based on Mustache or uses a similar syntax?

All I could find is `haml`, `jade`, `ejs`, `jquery templates` and one based on CoffeeScript (I write plain JS).

I want to write "normal" html, so only `ejs` and `jqtpl` would fit. I already use `mustache` with `backbone` so it would be best to also use it on the server side with Node.js

Comment: Hogan.js is mustache wrapper for express just -h flag to express app generator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably add Mustache as a rendering engine by following [the Express manual](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering):

> View filenames take the form “.”, where  is the name of the module >that will be required. For example the view layout.ejs will tell the view system to >require(‘ejs’), the module being loaded must export the method exports.compile(str, >options), and return a Function to comply with Express.

Edit:
From [the Mustache manual](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) under Usage:

> Below is quick example how to use mustache.js:

```
var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function () {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
};

var output = Mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", view);
```

> In this example, the Mustache.render function takes two parameters: 1) the mustache >template and 2) a view object that contains the data and code needed to render the >template.

From the above I suspect you could just export Mustache.render, but I haven't tested it. The object literals used as data look the same, but if they do happen to be different, you could probably just wrap Mustache.render in a function that formats it correctly.

Edit: Xomby's wrapper link contains an example of how to wrap handlebars for express, Mustache should be similar.

Answer (score 7):

Just stumbled on this ancient thread but no one has mentioned consolidate.js, which seems to be the "right" way under Express 3 (refer to http://expressjs.com/faq.html). It also provides an easy way to switch/experiment with templating systems.

Here's a simple example - http://invitingthebell.com/2012/12/24/mustache-templates-in-express-3-0/.

Code, in case it disappears is:

```
var express = require('express')
 , cons = require('consolidate')
 , app = express();

// assign the mustache engine to .html files
app.engine('html', cons.mustache);

// set .html as the default extension 
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// test mustache
app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
  var viewdata = { 'test' : 'Hey now.'};
  res.render('index', viewdata);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The index.html file in the views directory:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Some CMS</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Mustache</h1>
    <p>What do you say?</p>
    <p>{{test}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try Hogan.js http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/

I think it's what Twitter and LinkedIn uses in production.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example/tutorial on using NodeJS, ExpressJS and MustacheJS Template Engine:

http://devcrapshoot.com/javascript/nodejs-expressjs-and-mustachejs-template-engine

You can build out a complete web page like you normally would, placing the mustacheJS fields where you like.  Use express to route to the page, use node fs.readFileSync(); to get the html file, use mustache to update the data on the page then spit it out to the client.

It's kinda neat.  I hope it helps!

-A-

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried [stache](https://github.com/fat/stache) ? It is no longer maintained but you can follow some links and get more recent stuff ..

Answer (score 1):

I found [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) which is an extension of the Mustache template system/language.

And there is a really simple [wrapper](https://github.com/donpark/hbs) to use it with Express.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the best way to do this is the post here:

http://iamtherockstar.com/blog/2011/11/21/using-mustache-templates-express-apps/

So far, this has worked great for me.  The only problem I have found is not using partials at the root path for views.  For example partials in view/partials - the engine by default only finds partials as view.  Let me know if you figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Handlerbars. " Handlebars provides the power necessary to let you build semantic templates effectively with no frustration.
Handlebars is largely compatible with Mustache templates. In most cases it is possible to swap out Mustache with Handlebars and continue using your current templates. Complete details can be found [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js#differences-between-handlebarsjs-and-mustache) " - [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com)